# Image placement in bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web dev, so please bear with me. I have to create a block with a set of images like this: [image]

I tried using a table to do this, but the image propotions of the last columns aren't correct. I believe that coz of the height of the rows. I managed to get the center image correctly by using `rowspan`. I looked up numerous tutorials online but couldn't find one where the middle image is like this. I tried using `li` too. But failed. This is the code of the table I have

```
<table class="home" align="center">

        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://localhost/sty_partners/img/main_top_left.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" >

            </td>
            <td rowspan ="2"><img src="http://localhost/sty_partners/img/main_center.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block">
            <!--<div class="center" > <p> SPEND MORE <br> time doing what <br> you love</p> </div>-->
            </td>
            <td><img src="http://localhost/sty_partners/img/main_top_right.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://localhost/sty_partners/img/main_bottom_left.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block"></td>

            <td><img src="http://localhost/sty_partners/img/main_bottom_right.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block"></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is the CSS for the table:

```
table.home img{
width:100%; height:100%;}
```

Can someone please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the bootstrap grid system for this. 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

You'll probably need to add some custom css classes to adjust the padding the way you want and to make all columns the same height.  Lots of tutorials online for this (do a quick google search).

Comment: I tried the columns too. The thing is, that way I can't make the center image the same height of the images on either side of it

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks Mike

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do most of this with Bootstrap columns alone. If you're unfamiliar with the grid system or need clarification, I would go to W3C: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp.
If that alone won't work, you'll probably need to use your own CSS as well. W3C has great info on CSS as well:http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp. Without further details I can't tell you much else. Perhaps using the background-image property would work?